# Internet speed slow on certain website using ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, 21.10

I've a ~200 Mbps wired connection (given by university), I'm getting around 300 KBps speed while downloading [microsoft teams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-teams/download-app#desktopAppDownloadregion)
I tried downloading from my friend's wifi (which uses the same connection) and I got around 4 MBps while downloading the same, (wifi speed cap is 80 Mbps), I've tried using wired connection in his room and got same results. What could be the possible reason of getting slower speed via ethernet. Other things seem to download normally, it is the Microsoft related things which are causing a pain.

Comment: Did you use the same wire?

Comment: No, I ve tested with various wires, I'm sure the problem isn't with the wire